# Returning a value when a column contains at least one match

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.3

Edit:  Sorry to not mention before this is on a postgres 8.3 implementation.

I have a table of four columns that was built today table.

```
Source_IP, Destination_IP, user_type, ut_bool
```

The `user_type` column continually gets new entries and so I want to compare it to a table o historical entries to see if it is new or not for the day in question. The `source_ip`, `destination_Ip` can be considered the primary key

```
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.1, type1, 0
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.1, type4, 1
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.4, type5, 0
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.4, type3, 0
10.1.1.2, 30.30.50.9, type2, 0
10.1.1.4, 30.30.30.4, type4, 0
10.1.1.4, 30.30.30.4, type3, 1
```

I am having trouble returning a 1 to a column for a given group of (`source_ip, destination_ip`) pairs if a least one `source_ip,destination_ip, user_type` pair has a 1 next to it so for example I want to get

```
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.1, 1
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.4, 0
10.1.1.4, 30.30.30.4, 1
```

I am not sure how to use the exists statement correctly.

**How do I fix the following query?**

```
select source_ip, destination_ip,
(
select
case when exists 
(select true from table
where ut_bool =1)
then '1'
else '0' end
) as ut_new
from
table;
```

My query keeps returning because I am not using the exists statement correctly:

```
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.1, 0
10.1.1.2, 30.30.30.4, 0
10.1.1.4, 30.30.30.4, 0
```

Comment: Please note that the tag [psql] is *not* for PostgreSQL but for its default command line terminal. Fixed it. Also please clarify: Are we dealing with one or two tables? Do you want to query for a single pair of `(source_ip, destination_ip)`, for a set of pairs or for a whole table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest modification of your SQL statement:

```
SELECT SOURCE_IP,
  DESTINATION_IP,
  CASE SUM(UT_BOOL)
    WHEN 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS UT_NEW
FROM test_table_name
GROUP BY SOURCE_IP,
  DESTINATION_IP;
```

Executed on your test data returns:

```
10.1.1.2    30.30.50.9  0
10.1.1.2    30.30.30.1  1
10.1.1.2    30.30.30.4  0
10.1.1.4    30.30.30.4  1
```

Tested and working on Oracle and Postgres

Comment: Thank you I was hoping to avoid scanning every row with a sum because this is on a table with over 4 Billion rows.  I was trying improve performance to use the exists clause so as to return a 1 as soon as at least one row for a fixed source_ip, destination_ip pair had a 1 next to any user_type.

Comment: @user7980 Your desired output suggests, that you want distinct pairs of source and destination IPs. When that is true, this answer is the way to go (`DISTINCT` is basically a `GROUP BY` on all columns, and then doing a `SUM()` makes no big difference).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Source_IP, Destination_IP
    , MAX(ut_bool) As the_value
FROM ztable
GROUP BY Source_IP, Destination_IP
    ;
```